# Jmeter - getting the exact accessibility time of a website

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter (performace testing)

Is there a way in jmeter where i can get the exact accessibility time of a website i created using docker image? As of now i am using timer to mesure the accessibility time(time of successful checking of website minus the creation if website using docker image) but it will continue to execute the HTTP request until all the HTTP is executed.

The scenario that i want is like this:
I will create a website using docker image then i will have to check the exact accessibility time(from creating up to launching/checking the site). Once the the requirement is met the timer will stop and it will give me the exact time on when it is actually up. This is the sample of my thread that i am using:

[image]

Please help me thank you!!1

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to looks into NewRelic website, basically all you need to add the dll.
It will capture the metric for the HTTP web request, you also able to go down to the database layer to see which database that slow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put your `Check Boilerplate Website` under the [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and set "Loop Count" to `Forever` (or reasonably high number of iterations)
2. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a child of the `Check Boilerplate Website` request
3. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if (prev.isSuccessful()) {
       prev.setStopTest(true)
   }
   ```

The above setup will execute `Check Boilerplate Website` request until it will be successful, the JMeter test will end once the request will be OK.

`prev` is a shorthand for the [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) class instance, check out JavaDoc for available functions and [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article to learn more about the concept of Groovy scripting in JMeter tests.

Comment: Thank you for this. I forgot 1 more thing, in the view result tree, i only want to get the last successful status. The View Result Tree will only show the successful status and will disregard the failed status. I that possible? thank you!